# How to convert list append with for, if, elif to list comprehension

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension

I' like to convert list append code with mulitple for and if, elif to list comprehension.
I tried but only temp_list worked.
temp_list2 did not work properly

Original code

```
temp_list = []
temp_array = accd['ACCD_SEQ'].values
temp_list = [i for i in temp_array if len(accd[accd['ACCD_DTL'].str.contains(i)]) != 0]

temp_list2 = []

for i in temp_list:
    if len(accd[accd['ACCD_DTL'].str.contains(i)]) == 1:
        temp_list2.append(i)
    elif len(accd[accd['ACCD_DTL'].str.contains(i)]) > 1:
        for j in range(len(accd[accd['ACCD_DTL'].str.contains(i)])):
            temp_list2.append(i)
    else:
        pass
```

My trial

```
temp_list2 = [i if len(accd[accd['ACCD_DTL'].str.contains(i)]) == 1 else i for j in range (len(accd[accd['ACCD_DTL'].str.contains(i)])) if len(accd[accd['ACCD_DTL'].str.contains(i)]) > 1 for i in temp_list
```

This code said "UnboundLocalError : local variable 'i' referenced before assignment"

Anyone can help to fix it?

Comment: I am not evaluating if your list comprehension is correct, but you should definitely say `[i for i in temp_list...]` instead of simply saying `[i if len...]`

Comment: try this,
[ i for i in temp_list if len(accd[accd['ACCD_DTL'].str.contains(i)]) == 1 elif len(accd[accd['ACCD_DTL'].str.contains(i)]) > 1  j for j in range(len(accd[accd['ACCD_DTL'].str.contains(i)])) ]

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the following function `sumlists`, which "flattens" numerical 2-dimensional lists by taking the sum of the values in every row that are larger than `1`:

```
def sumlists(lst):
    new_lst = []

    for i in range(len(lst)):
        sum_ = 0

        for j in range(len(lst[i])):
            if lst[i][j] > 1:
                sum_ += lst[i][j]

        new_lst.append(sum_)

    return new_lst
```

For instance, if `lst` is:

```
lst = [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 1, 6],
        [7, 1]
]
```

the output would be:

```
[5, 15, 7]
```

The function has two nested `for` loops with indices `i` and `j` to traverse `lst` rows and columns, respectively. Before going through the values in each row, we need to define a variable, in this case `sum_`, to hold the sum up to the *jth* value in the *ith* row. The condition `if lst[i][j] > 1:` prevents any number less than `2` from being added to `sum_`. Finally, when all the values in the *ith* row have been gone through, the resulting sum is appended to the "flattened" list (`new_list`). With this, let's break all this info down to make our way from the function definition to list comprehension.

Step 1. row for loop:

```
arr[i] for i in range(len(arr))
```

Step 2. column for loop:

```
arr[i][j] for j in range(len(arr[i]))] for i in range(len(arr))
```

Step 3. condition for the sake of the sum, values larger than one are returned, otherwise 0:

```
arr[i][j] if arr[i][j] > 1 else 0 for j in range(len(arr[i]))] for i in range(len(arr))
```

Step 4. sum: adding all the values in `[arr[i][j] if arr[i][j] > 1 else 0 for j in range(len(arr[i]))]`

```
sum([arr[i][j] if arr[i][j] > 1 else 0 for j in range(len(arr[i]))]) for i in range(len(arr))
```

Step 5. append the sums to the `new_lst`:

```
↓ here                                                                                        ↓ here
[sum([arr[i][j] if arr[i][j] > 1 else 0 for j in range(len(arr[i]))]) for i in range(len(arr))]
```

I hope this answers your question.